# Installing unixODBC Driver onto Ubuntu 18 for Snowflake... Error testing connection

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, unixodbc

Followed these how-tos:

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/odbc-linux.html#step-2-install-the-odbc-driver
and
https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/odbc-linux.html#step-3-configure-the-environment-tgz-only

I'm using unixODBC and have done the installation and configuration as listed but in step 5, I'm getting the error:

```
$ isql -v snowflake_dev my_username my_password
[IM002][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

My debug/config/connection info is as follows:

```
$ which odbcinst
/usr/bin/odbcinst
```

```
$ which isql
/usr/bin/isql
```

```
$ odbcinst -j
unixODBC 2.3.4
DRIVERS............: /etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /home/vagrant/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8
```

I ran the unixodbc_setup.sh script to init.
simba.snowflake.ini looks like this:

```
ANSIENCODING=UTF-8
DriverManagerEncoding=UTF-16
DriverLocale=en-US
ErrorMessagesPath=/var/snowflake_odbc/ErrorMessages/
LogLevel=0
LogNamespace=
LogPath=/var/snowflake_odbc/log
CURLVerboseMode=false
CABundleFile=/var/snowflake_odbc/lib/cacert.pem
ODBCInstLib=libodbcinst.so
```

odbcinst.ini looks like this:

```
[ODBC]
Trace=no
TraceFile=

[ODBC Drivers]
SnowflakeDSIIDriver=Installed

[SnowflakeDSIIDriver]
APILevel=1
ConnectFunctions=YYY
Description=Snowflake DSII
Driver=/var/snowflake_odbc/lib/libSnowflake.so
DriverODBCVer=03.52
SQLLevel=1
```

odbc.ini looks like this:

```
[ODBC Data Sources]
snowflake_dev = SnowflakeDSIIDriver

[snowflake_dev]
Driver      = /var/snowflake_odbc/lib/libSnowflake.so
Description = Snowflake Dev
server      = My_Server
role        = My_Role
database    = My_Database
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I was editing the odbc.ini and odbcinst.ini files in /var/snowflake_odbc/conf and should have been editing the files in /etc.